RestClient returns 403 after apache.httpclient5 upgrade from 5.3.1 to 5.4
I use RestClient.Builder to build a RestClient instance with a custom request factory backed by apache.httpclient5 in an application written with SpringBoot 3.3.6. Initially, apache.httpclient 5.3.1 was used and everything was working just fine. After upgrading the dependency to apache.httpclient 5.4 all initiated requests started to fail with 403 [No body] response. Downgrading back to 5.3.1 solved the issue. Does anyone know what could be causing the issue and how to fix it?
Here's how the RestClient is constructed:
ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings settings = 
    ClientHttpRequestFactorySettings.DEFAULTS
        .withConnectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120))
        .withReadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120));
var requestFactory = ClientHttpRequestFactories.get(settings);

// RestClient.Builder restClientBuilder

var restClient = restClientBuilder
    .requestFactory(requestFactory)
    .baseUrl(url)
    .build();

Thank you

You are not using Envoy by any chance, are you?

good question. I guess we are. The service is running in a k8s cluster with istio enabled so I assume envoy is there. Does it ring a bell?

Please see Spring Boot 3.4 Release Notes. Some reverse proxies such as Envoy incorrectly handle the Upgrade: TLS request header and deny access to the resource.
There are two ways to address the problem

Kindly ask Envoy developers to fix the handling of Upgrade: TLS on their end
Disable TLS upgrade on the client end by either using custom RequestConfig as described in the Spring Boot release notes.


Interesting. We're using SpringBoot 3.3 and it does not include the classes suggested in the workaround. Let me try to figure it out.
